# setting an active img from page load

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm currently using the following jQuery code to do img hover and click. The thing is, I want the menuleft_off img to load as the menuleft_on img without it stopping the jQuery code from working.

So in other words I want the menuleft img to load on the page as if I have already clicked it.

---

i have changed "images/menuleft_off.png" to "images/menuleft_on.png". now when i click on the "images/menuright_off.png" to change the tab the "images/menuleft_on.png" stays as _on and doesnt change until i hover over it. any tips on how to get "images/menuleft_on.png" to change to "images/menuleft_off.png" when i click on the "images/menuright_off.png" tab/image??

---

**HTML:**

```
<div id="toptabs" class="maintabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#" rel="tcontent1" class="selected"><img src="images/menuleft_off.png" width="277" height="42" class="img-swap" /></a></li>
        <li><a href="#" rel="tcontent2"><img src="images/menuright_off.png" width="277" height="42" class="img-swap" /></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
jQuery(function(){
    $(".img-swap:not(.active)").hover(
    function(){this.src = this.src.replace("_off","_on");},
    function(){
        if(!$(this).hasClass('active')){
            this.src = this.src.replace("_on","_off");
        }
    });
    $(".img-swap").click(function(){
        $(".img-swap.active").each(function(){
            this.src = this.src.replace("_on","_off");
            $(this).removeClass('active');
        });
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
    });
});
```

Comment: I don't see java code in this question.

Comment: Uhm, did you try just changing the source in the HTML ?

Comment: You could just change the image src to _on ?

Comment: I have tried changing menuleft_off to _on but then when I click the other image (menuright_off) the hover script doesnt work. It is probably a simple fix. I was just to tried to see it.

Comment: i have changed "images/menuleft_off.png" to "images/menuleft_on.png". now when i click on the "images/menuright_off.png" to change the tab the "images/menuleft_on.png" stays as _on and doesnt change until i hover over it. any tips on how to get "images/menuleft_on.png" to change to "images/menuleft_off.png" when i click on the "images/menuright_off.png" tab/image??